# Trouble with CSS Hover and Active

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the image of the button when its on hover and active, currently it will show the button but when you go to hover over it doesn't change, I've tried giving the buttons there own id as well as just replacing the current image with another but it doesn't work.

html:

```
 <div id="navcontainer" class="column five">
        <ul id="navmain">
            <li><a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="philosophy.html" id="btnphil">Philosophy</a></li>
            <li><a href="econews.html" id="btnnews">Eco News</a></li>
            <li><a href="diy.html" id="btndiy">DIY</a></li>
            <li><a href="takeaction.html" id="btntake">Take Action </a></li>        </ul>
    </div><!-- .sidebar#sideLeft -->
```

---

CSS:

```
#navcontainer{
padding:10px 30px; 
width:220px;
float: left;
margin-top:480px;
}


#navmain li{
list-style:none;
}
#navmain li, #navmain a{
text-decoration:none;
height:38px;
width:153px;
background-image: url('../images/button.png') ;
   background-position: center;
   text-align: center;
   color:#000;
   margin-left:-10px;
   margin-top:20px;
  vertical-align: -22%;



#navmain, #home a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
height:38px;
width:153px;
background-image: url('../images/buttonhover.png') ;
   background-position: center;
   text-align: center;
   color:#000;
   margin-left:-10px;
   margin-top:20px;;}
}

#navmain a:active {
   border-top-color: #297ab0;
   background: #297ab0;
   }
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: It's because your putting the background on the LI and A on the normal state, then on hover you just change only the A. Stick with just the A.

Answer (score 3):

You have to clean up you CSS selectors.  You're not being consistent:

```
// This is applying the image
#navmain li, #navmain a{...}

// This is swapping but it starts with "#home" instead of "#navmain"
#navmain, #home a:hover {...}
```

So try:

```
#navmain a:hover{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#home:hover
```

Or

```
#navmain #home:hover
```

Or

```
a#home:hover
```

Comment: They all do the same in this case, so I would recommend the first one as the least specific.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS is wrong:

```
#navmain, #home a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    height:38px;
    width:153px;
    background-image: url('../images/buttonhover.png') ;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

The element should be set against `#navmain a:hover, #home a:hover`

Also not sure if it's a copy paste issue but you are missing the closing bracket for `#navmain li, #navmain a`, but that causes another problem if you are.